# ef database updata is unable to find migration

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to perform a consolidation or merge of migrations on one of many DBContexts.
We have a .NET 6 solution which utilizes several databases. All db contexts have been defined in a single project, in separate folders. I.e.

```
Solution\
- Business_Logic_Project_1\
- Business_Logic_Project_2\
- Business_Logic_Project_3\
- Database_Project\
    - Context1\
        - Migrations\
        - Models\
        - Context1.cs
    - Context2\
        - Migrations\
        - Models\
        - Context2.cs
    - Context3\
        - Migrations\
        - Models\
        - Context3.cs
    - Database_Project.csproj
- Startup_Project
    - Startup_Project.csproj
- Solution.sln
```

I do the following:
I open a command prompt and go to the root of the solution.
I then delete all migrations in the Database_Project\Context2\Migrations.
I then execute this command:

```
dotnet ef migrations add <<MIGRATION_NAME>> --context Context2 --project Database_Project --startup-project Startup_Project --output-dir Context2\Migrations
```

I empty the __EFMigrationsHistory table in the database.
Finally, I run this command to finish the consolidation:

```
dotnet ef database update <<MIGRATION_NAME>> --context Context2 --project Database_Project --startup-project Startup_Project
```

This fails with the error message: `The migration '<<MIGRATION_NAME>>' was not found.`

So, I *think* this is because the migrations are placed under the context folders, and the database update command do not look that deep. There doesn't appear to be a way of telling the command where to look for migrations though, so what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out, but I forgot about this question, so I can't remember the issue and how I solved it.

However, I found that these steps works:

- Step 1: Delete all *.cs files under the Migrations folder. Except the *ModelSnapshot.cs.
- Step 2: Copy all records from the __EFMigrationHistory to the __EFMigrationHistoryBackup:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.[__EFMigrationHistoryBackup] (MigrationId, ProductVersion) 
SELECT MigrationId, ProductVersion FROM dbo.[__EFMigrationsHistory]
```

- Step 3: Empty the __EFMigrationHistory table:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.[__EFMigrationHistory]
```

- Step 4: Create a new migration like: dotnet ef migrations add Migration_Merge_2022Q4.
  Both the Up() and Down() methods of the migration should be empty. If not, comment out all code inside the two methods.
- Step 5: Update the database like: dotnet ef database update. This should add a new record in the __EFMigrationHistory table, but since Up() and Down() is empty, no changes is made to the database.
- Step 6: Uncomment the Up() and Down() methods.
- Step 7: Check the changes into Git.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to pinpoint the exact reason but, while providing the migration name in update command, did you include the `.cs` extension? If so, please try without that.

Other possibilities include

- some typo in the command
- missing migration designer files

Comment: I only use the migration name, without the .cs and the timestamp at the beginning. The designer files are present. Of course the typo is a possibility, I'll check.